# Can I create two separate ranges on a single Slider in Material UI v5?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I was exploring Material UI v5 Sliders and was wondering if it is possible to have two separate ranges on a single slider, as in 2 pairs of thumbs and 2 distinct tracks? I can't quite figure it out and it's driving me crazy.

I tried creating two separate ranges as pairs and then later one range with 4 thumbs and tried to get the track between 2 and 3 to not render but can't get it to happen.
I'm using React and mui v5. This is just a curiousity exercise as I get to know mui but I would some solutions to help me comprehend things better.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.